# Android - Starting and Killing an App from another App

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, kill

I am using [AndroidAsync](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync) to host a server on my Android device. I want to be able to launch a new application upon a POST request, and kill that application upon a DELETE request. However, the application may finish by itself and thus I want to be able to get results from the application upon its completion.

Here is how I launch the application:

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.app.package");
startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
```

Here is how I try to kill the application:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("am force-stop com.app.package");
```

Here is the code I have on the other application (the one being launched and killed):

```
public boolean kill;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...

    final Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);

    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                if (!kill) {
                    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sleep 10");
                    p.waitFor();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
            }

            finish();
        }
    }.start();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    kill = true;
}
```

When I try to kill the application, nothing happens.

I am at a loss as to why this doesn't work. I am thinking that I will have to root my device to be able to get the "am force-stop" command to do anything though, is this right?

EDIT:

When I run "am force-stop com.app.package" in the adb shell while the application is running, it stops. Why doesn't it work when I do it programmatically?

Comment: Should be `public volatile boolean kill;` since you write to it inside one thread and read it from another.

Answer (score 2):

#### Problem 0: `startActivityForResult()` immediately triggers `onActivityResult()`

If you call an external app with

```
Intent intent = this.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.app.package");
```

that would create an intent with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` added by default. And an intent that has this flag set triggers `onActivityResult()` immediately. So call:

```
intent.setFlags(0);
```

which will clear all flags, and then you can proceed to:

```
startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_CODE);
```

#### Problem 1: Can't kill a launched application

If you want to stop a created process basing on its package name try

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
am.killBackgroundProcesses("com.app.package");
```

You must hold the permission [`android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES) to be able to call this method. <sup>([read more about `killBackgroundProcesses()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#killBackgroundProcesses(java.lang.String)))</sup>

**UPD**. See the [author](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4543614/infamous911)'s solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37864816/1429387).

Comment: This solved that problem, thank you. However, the core problem still exists and I have edited my post to reflect that.

Comment: @Infamous911 See update. Please, tell us about the results; I'm not 100% sure that it's a working solution.

Comment: Doesn't work. Application remains in the foreground after the call (and with the permission).

Comment: @Infamous911 Why? See [Android log](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14430/how-can-i-view-and-examine-the-android-log).

Comment: Android log shows nothing when I try to close it: 06-16 08:53:40.180   592   623 I ActivityManager: Displayed com.app.package/.MainActivity: +576ms (total +36s734ms)
06-16 08:53:50.191   592   618 I ActivityManager: Killing 3092:com.google.android.gms:car/u0a8 (adj 15): empty #17 (here it is displayed, and then killed after 10 seconds, but not killed in between, which is when I send the DELETE request)

Comment: I have posted an update question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37864816/android-kill-app-from-another-app-on-a-rooted-device